# Django mutiple class Meta: being executed

Tags: django, tastypie

```
class A(ModelResource):
    Meta:
    resource_name = 'urlA'
    print helloA
class B(ModelResource):
    Meta:
    resource_name = 'urlB'
    print helloB
```

I get helloA and helloB printed when I access /urlA. I only expected helloA. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. hope this is not your actual indentation
2. the whole module (file containing those classes) is being loaded at the server startup (or later, thanks to the lazy loading). it has **nothing** to do with the url being loaded (called).
3. don't know what you mean by "being executed" ... neither what you wanted to achieve with that code. Please, do a few steps back and learn basics of python, that will make your life easier.